# Do not allow locking read only files by network

Tags: windows, ntfs, network-shares, smb, shared-folders

I have shared a folder with `read-only` access rights. But if someone is using files from this folder, I can not delete these files, because they are locked. Is there any way to prevent read-only users from being able to interfere with normal users (who has full access rights)?